# Stopping random UITableViewCells being affected when specifying a cell with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm very new to iOS and Swift development, but I'm loving it so far.

I've got a tableview that's scrollable and contains a number of cells populated by an array of a custom struct.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("platformCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PlatformCell
    cell.platformName.text = KeyPlatformsViewController.platforms[indexPath.row].platformName
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: KeyPlatformsViewController.platforms[indexPath.row].platformColour)
    return cell
}
```

The problem is I want to put something like this in the code:

```
        if  cell.platformName.text == "A" {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
        }
```

But with the deque cell (I think) the wrong cells are being targetted after scrolling the view.

Does anyone know of a way to make sure only the one I've selected gets affected?

I hope I was clear, I don't think I'm explaining this very well.

Comment: Where are you adding the if cell.platformName.text == "A" etc code? In the .m of your custom cell class?

Comment: @LeeJPollard I'm adding it before the return cell call in that first method I posted.

Comment: Try adding that code in the .m of your custom cell class. Basically, try overloading the setter of the cell's platformName property with the if self.platformName.text == "A" code. Ideally, any custom UI work you do on your cell should be done in the custom cell class itself.

Comment: @LeeJPollard Sticking it in the override func setSelected() method doesn't work with that - as in it'll do it to other cells too.

Comment: If you include your if self.platformName.text == "A" code in the custom cell class, then it will only affect cells where their platformName.text == "A"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the value of something in a cell based on an if statement, you should always include an "else" clause to take care of the other case (or other cases , in which case you need some if-elses).

```
    if  KeyPlatformsViewController.platforms[indexPath.row].platformName == "A" {
         cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
    }else{
        cell.backgroundColor = ... // default color 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, you want to change the color of text based on some data condition you should be checking or validating the data (in your case the text content from datasource) not the UI (text set in the cell).

So instead of checking

`if cell.platformName.text == "A"`

check

`if KeyPlatformsViewController.platforms[indexPath.row].platformName == "A"`

This way, in [MVC architecture](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html) terms, your data (model) drives your UI (view).

Comment: Please edit your question with updated code for better understanding.